# Calcular Valor JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função para o calculo total.

```
$('.valor').blur(function(){
    var valor = $("input[name=valor]").val() || 0;
    var descontos = $("input[name=descontos]").val() || 0;
    var juros = $("input[name=juros]").val() || 0;

    valor_cobrado = (parseFloat(valor) - parseFloat(descontos)) + parseFloat(juros);
    $("#valor_cobrado").val(parseFloat(valor_cobrado));
});
```

Os campos tem mascara de moeda com virgula mas o valor total não está levando em consideração a virgula.

exemplo 10,50 + 11,00 = 21,00

Comment: O JS utiliza o formato internacional, considerando o ponto como separador decimal. Se o seu campo está formatado com vírgula, você precisará tratá-lo antes de fazer operações matemáticas.

Comment: Esse código funciona corretamente? Pelo que me parece ocorre isso: digita um valor no campo com class valor, quando vc clica em outro campo a ação blur é executada e dai pra frente nada mais ocorre a não ser que volte a clicar no input class valor e clique fora de novo Ou será que estou enganado? O usuário terá que ter poderes magicos para fazer desse modo, ou seja, depois de tudo preenchido provocar o blur de novo

Comment: é exatamente isso, assim que o usuário digita o valor e sai do campo, o valor total é calculado. Uso a .valor para os 3 inputs

Comment: isso quer dizer que ao digitar o valor e sair os demais valores já existem?

Comment: Não, conforme ele vai digitando, vai calculando.
Se ele digitar no campo Valor, e deixar zerado nos outros, o campo Valor total será preenchido.

Comment: é como eu disse, depois de todos preenchidos tem que clicar no campo valor e provocar o blur novamente clicando fora dele para realizar a matematica

Comment: Por que blur novamente, se tu já digitou uma vez já calculou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JS não trabalha com vírgula, tem que trocar por ponto.

```
valor.replace(',', '.')
```

Depois volta pra vígula.

```
valor.replace('.', ',')
```